# Varying R-squared value

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics, scikit-learn, r-squared

I'm new to machine learning, I have been doing a multiple linear regression (with 3 features,1 target). I'm using train_test_split module from sklearn to split the data into training and test data. Each time when I run the model I get different R-square values such as **0.6, 0.7, -0.122, 0.2, 0.9**. How can I interpret this varying R-square value for the multiple linear regression? Is this behavior suggesting me to go for a non-linear regression?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are doing something wrong. First $R^2$ can't be negative. Second, while there could be some variation in it on re-runs of the model, what you post is not reasonable.  But we'd need to know a lot more to be able to tell what you are doing wrong.  It could be your  N is too small, it could be an error in the code, it could be a problem in how you are splitting the data, and I'm sure there are other posssibilities.

Comment: My data set is too small it contains only 18 rows, Training data size is 14 and test data size is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, your whole data set is 18 and you've split it into 14 for training and 4 for test.

So, in your test data, you have 4 cases and 3 variables. That's way way overfit.  Even if you split it into 9 and 9, you can only sensibly look at one independent variable with so little data.

You need either a much simpler model or a lot more data.

Comment: What do you mean by a simpler method? Could you please provide me an example. Adding that my residual plot showing a trend or structure when splitting the data 50% for train and 50% for a test. Whether this a indication to go for a non-linear model

Comment: A simpler model - that is, one with fewer independent variables. In fact, you only have enough data for one independent variable.